# ReactJS: Check the render method of `MainRouter`. Error

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to export two named modules from one component file and somehow keep getting the "Check the render method..." error.

Here's a look at my code.

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { MainRouter } from '../Router';

const App = () => (
  <div className="card">
    <MainRouter />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Router.jsx - which is what's being imported above

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
import Header from './components/Header';
import AdminNav from './components/AdminNav';

import Calendar from './pages/Calendar';
import Search from './pages/Search';
import AdminLogin from './pages/AdminLogin';
import Admin from './pages/Admin';
import New from './pages/Admin/New';
import Users from './pages/Admin/Users';

let styles = {};

styles.body__wrapper = {
  padding: '2%'
};

export const MainRouter = () => (
  <Router>
    <Fragment>
      <div className="nav__wrapper">
        <Header />
      </div>
      <div style={styles.body__wrapper}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Calendar} />
          <Route path="/search/:name" component={Search} />
          <Route path="/admin/signin" component={AdminLogin} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        </Switch>sasd
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  </Router>
);

export const AdminRouter = (props) => (
  <div className="container">
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        <AdminNav {...props}/>
        <div className="my-3">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
            <Route path="/new" component={New} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```

I've tried doing export { MainRouter, AdminRouter } but doesn't seem to work as well.

Complete error message:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MainRouter`.
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: @raksheetbhat added error message on main post.

Comment: I think you missed return statement in ur const App

Comment: I sort of figured it out. Some exports on several index.js files for the routes were incorrectly written.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out.

I was using several index.js on every route component and incorrectly configured the exports on almost all of them, causing the whole app to crash.